# A question on Electromagnetic induction and relative motion

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, relative-motion

It's a well-known fact that a changing electric or magnetic field induces current, but what if I'm moving in such a way that relative to me there is no change in flux due to whatever external factors. IN that case, will I be able to harness the current that a stationary observer can?

Comment: Cann you explain how you waant to move to avoid seeing changing flux, if the B field does not change the wire will move and vice versa?

Comment: let's say that a rod is  rotating, if I''m rotating in the opposite direction, relative to me, the rod is stationary

Comment: If you are rotating, then the reference frame where you are stationary is not an inertial frame.

Comment: so most of these theories are developed on a way that they only hold true n an inertial frame?